# Strange change in ConstraintLayout behavior from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have noticed a strange change in ConstraintLayout behavior from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3 which can cause a lot of problems in layout. In addition, I personally believe it is a bug, because this behavior should be incorrect.

Check following Layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    
<Button
    android:id="@+id/test1_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/test2_btn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/test2_btn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/test2_btn"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test2_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/test1_btn"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how this layout is rendered in both version `1.1.2` and `1.1.3` of `ConstraintLayout`:

[image]

Now we add `android:visibility="gone"` to `test1_btn`. In `ConstraintLayout` version `1.1.2`, layout is rendered as follows:

[image]

**This is completely logical**, because we have `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"` set, so `test2_btn` should stay at far right of the chain. Now if we use `ConstraintLayout` version `1.1.3`, layout will be rendered as follows:

[image]

**Just what happened? Why I lost chain bias?**

Comment: I don't believe that this is a Bug. Rather a feature :D You could use Barriers if your constraint Layout does contain GONE Widgets. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier

Comment: @JohnDoe I can solve this problem with barrier, But I still think this behavior is a bug. Because if I don't have `test1_btn` at all (rather than setting to `gone`), view goes to right most of screen which is logical. It is funny if I don't go when another control is there and I have made a chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the old behavior while still using version 1.1.3, add this attribute to your `<ConstraintLayout>` tag:

```
app:layout_optimizationLevel="direct|barrier"
```

Version 1.1 of the ConstraintLayout library introduced [new optimizations](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-constraint-layout-1-1-d07fc02406bc). These optimizations parse your ConstraintLayout and look for constraints that can be removed or simplified.

As of version 1.1.2, the only optimizations enabled by default were **direct** and **barrier**. Version 1.1.3 *also* [enables **chain** by default](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/08/constraintlayout-113.html). You can return to the 1.1.2 behavior by manually specifying which optimizations should be enabled.

---

For another way to show that this is the real issue, I tried *enabling* the chain optimizations while using version 1.1.2.

The first screenshot is taken using version 1.1.2 and your posted layout (with the `android:gone` attribute added). I then added this attribute to the root `ConstraintLayout` tag:

```
app:layout_optimizationLevel="chains"
```

and now I see the same behavior you found in version 1.1.3:

[image]
[image]

Comment: anyway, I guess this shows that layout behavior is somehow *undefined behavior* in this context. I don't think changing optimization should change how layouts are rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I looks like you have identified a problem, but not for the reason you think IMHO. If you look at the [documention](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#CenteringPositioning) for `ConstraintLayout` bias under "Positioning," it states:

> The default when encountering such opposite constraints is to center the widget; but you can tweak the positioning to favor one side over another using the bias attributes:

`layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` would apply to the widget and not the chain. Bias of a chain is affected, however, if the chain is a packed chain and bias is applied to a widget in the chain. It is unclear what should happen when the chain is `spread_inside` since this chain type dictates that the end widgets adhere to the sides.

The same documentation states:

> `GONE` widgets, as usual, are not going to be displayed and are not part of the layout itself (i.e. their actual dimensions will not be changed if marked as `GONE`).
>
> But in terms of the layout computations, `GONE` widgets are still part of it, with an important distinction:
>
> - For the layout pass, their dimension will be considered as zero (basically, they will be resolved to a point)
> - If they have constraints to other widgets they will still be respected, but any margins will be as if equals to zero

So, a `GONE` widget should still participate in the chain - it just has dimensions of zero. In your example, I would expect the right `TextView` to remain stationary when the visibility of the left `TextView` is changed to `GONE`. So, the behavior of 1.1.2 seems to be correct while 1.1.3 does seem to be inconsistent with the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with a lot of Cheticamp's answer, but I want to call some things out.

> It is unclear what should happen when the chain is spread_inside since this chain type dictates that the end widgets adhere to the sides.

Bias applies in only two situations:

- On a view with a fixed size that is constrained on both sides
- On the chain head of a packed chain

In the case of a spread-inside chain, bias has no effect; other constraints override it.

> So, a GONE widget should still participate in the chain - it just has dimensions of zero.

This is the real crux of the issue. I see the line of the documentation that says "in terms of the layout computations, GONE widgets are still part of it", so I understand how you'd conclude this.

*However*, I think there's an argument to be made in the other direction. Instead of a chain of two elements, imagine a chain of three. With the chain head `VISIBLE`, you'd expect to see

```
View1 <--- space ---> View2 <--- space ---> View3
```

Now, when you set the chain head to `GONE`, what would you expect? I think that most developers would rather see this:

```
View2 <-------------- space --------------> View3
```

than this:

```
<----- space ----> View2 <----- space ----> View3
```

If you agree, and you think that *usually* an Android developer would rather see the still-`VISIBLE` views of a spread-inside chain be pushed to the edges "as normal", then I think that the logical conclusion of that argument is the new behavior visible in v1.1.3.

I think the documentation should be updated to clarify this situation. Either `GONE` views participate in a chain (just as an invisible point), **or** `GONE` views don't participate in the chain (except in terms of chain-head attributes modifying the chain as a whole).

Comment: It looks like the OP filed a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120001944), so we can follow along. My bet is that this really is a bug and that 1.1.2 has the correct behavior, although it could be a change and the documentation needs to catch up. Either way, there is a problem.

Comment: Interestingly, 2.0.0-alpha2 seems to have the same behavior as 1.1.2 for OP's layout. However, if there are more than 2 views in the chain and the head is set to `GONE` then it's not taken into consideration when positioning the other views (they are spread evenly). In both 1.1.2 and 2.0.0-a2 there are also some weird things going on with the bias when trying OP's layout with chain's head `GONE`. It affects the positioning of `test2_btn` but only for values greater than 0.5

Comment: I've added another answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/53490256/8298909 ) that actually addresses the cause of OP's issue and how to fix it. I sort of feel like I should leave this one up, though, since I do feel that it adds to the conversation.